# Elementary questions regarding classes with Tkinter as an example

Tags: python, class, tkinter, frame, init

I was following the tutorial example here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCLTv6wh3jE

I modified the source code a bit (basically import Tkinter instead of from Tkinter import *)

```
#more complexed gui

import Tkinter

class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    """a gui application with 3 buttons"""

    def __init__(self,master):
        """Initialize the Frame"""
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """create 3 buttons that do nothing"""
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="this is the 1st button")
        self.button1.grid()

        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self)
        self.button2.grid()
        self.button2.configure(text="this is 2nd butt")

        self.button3 = Tkinter.Button(self)
        self.button3.grid()
        self.button3["text"] = "this is 3rd butt"

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("some GUI")
root.geometry("1024x768")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I realize that if I take out the `master` from `Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,master)`, the code still runs, not only that, I can run `app=Application(root)` and create multiple triple buttons.

So my question is:

1. what exactly does 'master' do?
2. if I take out the master from `__init__(self,master)`, it will gives me an error about not having enough arguments
3. also, I don't need to use `app=Application(root)`, I can just run `Application(root)` and that still makes `root.mainloop()` to work, so what's the purpose of that `app = Application(root)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions in order

1. The `master` argument is the "parent widget" for each widget, and defaults to `None` for `Tkinter.Frame`. Note you pass `self` (i.e. the `Frame`) as `master` to each `Button`;
2. That's not really a question, but if you change the definition to `def __init__(self)` then call `app = Application(root)` you will get a `TypeError`, as the `root` argument has nowhere to go; and
3. The point of setting `app = Application(root)` is simply that you can then access it later. Your example is simple, with no instance methods to call outside `__init__`, but that may not always be the case.

To clarify on 1., note that

```
class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
```

means that all `Application` class instances *inherit* methods and attributes from `Tkinter.Frame`. This is *not* the same as the function arguments in e.g.

```
def __init__(self, master):
```

which means that `Application.__init__` takes two arguments (the first, called `self` by convention in all instance methods, is the class instance itself and is usually passed implicitly). When you call

```
app = Application(root)
```

this relates to the `__init__` definition, and (roughly) means

```
Application.__init__(app, root)
```

If `__init__` doesn't have two arguments (`self` and `master`), you will therefore get a `TypeError`, as there are two arguments (the implicit instance `self` and explicit parent widget `master`) and Python only knows what to do with one of them.

Comment: Could you explain Application(root), I mean, the class is defined as class Application(Tkinter.Frame), it is already taking the argument "Tkinter.Frame", passing root to it doesn't quite make sense to me. Also, what do you mean by root argument has no where to go? Thanks,

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe, I am still confused but I think I am more confused about classes and OOP in general, I will have to check out some more tutorials then come back to this. Thank you for the explanation nonetheless.